# Google Maps iOS SDK, delayed update of map when changing camera

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

I have a setup where I use a custom overlay view that is displayed above the Google iOS SDK GMSMapView. It provides rich content and an interface on top of the map and also drives the current camera and zoom level of the GMSMapView beneath it. One could say the GMSMapView provides the background for the my content.

I set the current camera using GMSMapView -setCamera:.

The problem is that GMSMapView appears to be trying to optimize its load on the system. My overlay uses of potentially many core animation layers which need to be updated when the camera of the map changes.

When my overlay is "empty" so updating and redrawing its state based on location changes is quick, the GMSMapView update is almost instant (there's a tiny but acceptable delay).

The longer my overlay content update requires, the longer the GMSMapView waits to update to the new camera after I'm calling -setCamera:

It just seems to wait until the CPU is idling and does its update then. This causes an increasing lag between my overlay update and the map update.

Is there a way to make the camera update instantly, synchronously with the call to -setCamera: ?

Thanks
Markus